# cupyで処理中の配列の結合について

Tags: python

失礼します。

現在配列の結合を試みているのですが問題がありました。

```
<type 'cupy.core.core.ndarray'>)
```

このタイプの配列同士を結合するには、一度cupy->numpyつまりgpu->cpuに変換し、numpy.concatenate等で結合するしかないのでしょうか。

↑より効率よく結合できる方法があればご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cupy.concatenateを使えばnumpy.concatenateと同じことができるはずです。

Comment: 解決できました。大変助かりました。